# Deploying sinatra app (with config.ru) on heroku cedar stack

Tags: ruby, deployment, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to refactor my sinatra code to separate my main file into separate files, using some tips from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030173/111884), and I'm having troubles deploying to heroku.

Previously I didn't have a `config.ru` file, and just used my `Procfile`, which was:

```
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT
```

as per [this article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby).

From the refactor, I've now changed my `Procfile` to

```
web: bundle exec thin -R config.ru start -p $PORT
```

With my `config.ru` file being

```
root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)
require ::File.join( root, 'web' )
run MyApp.new
```

And my `web.rb` file being contained around a class definition

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  # ...
end
```

This works on my local development computer, but when I deploy to heroku, I get

```
2011-12-01T11:21:54+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2011-12-01T11:21:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2011-12-01T11:21:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-12-01T11:22:01+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET [my app].herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-12-01T11:22:02+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET [my app].herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Is thin not installed on heroku? Or is there some other way of running my app on heroku with the changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to update my `Procfile` because the `RACK_ENV` isn't passed into the heroku environment. The `Procfile` became:

```
web: bundle exec thin -R config.ru start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

Comment: Ok, so I didn't need to change config.ru to use Sinatra::Application instead of MyApp.new at all. Removing it from the answer.