# Bundle and Gem Errors when deploying Sinatra app to heroku

Tags: ruby, deployment, heroku, sinatra

UPDATE

I did the following and this is the callstack I am still getting in the logs:

```
2012-08-06T12:30:57+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-06T12:30:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p 56970`
2012-08-06T12:30:59+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
2012-08-06T12:31:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2012-08-06T12:31:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-06T12:31:08+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET arcane-garden-1058.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-06T12:31:08+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET arcane-garden-1058.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-06T12:31:09+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET arcane-garden-1058.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-06T12:31:10+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET arcane-garden-1058.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My Procfile file now looks like this:

```
root: = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)
require: ::File.join( root, 'app' )
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT
run: WPL.new
```

Gemfile looks like this:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'thin'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'json'
```

My app.rb looks like this now:
    require 'shotgun'
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'mongo'
    require 'json/pure'

```
class WPL < Sinatra::Application 
  db = Mongo::Connection.new.db('docs')


  get '/' do
    File.read(File.join('public', 'index.html'))
  end
end
```

And config.ru looks like this:

```
require './app'
run WPL.new
```

---

So I'm trying to deploy my app and I've run into several issues. Everything works fine locally.  I push the app to heroku and everything seems to be ok but when I check the logs it says it cant find command 'bundle'.

This is what my Procfile looks like.

```
web: bundle exec ruby app.rb -p $PORT
```

I tried removing `bundle exec` and just went with `ruby app.rb -p $POST` got further in the process but more errors.

The next set of errors I get are all gem related.  It simply can't find any of the gems that are required.  This is what my app.rb looks like.

```
require 'shotgun'
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'json/pure'


db = Mongo::Connection.new.db('docs')


get '/' do
  File.read(File.join('public', 'index.html'))
end
```

My Gemfile looks like this.

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'json'
```

My config.ru looks like this.

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Running `heroku run console` also results in this error `bundle: command not found`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your Procfile is not using your config.ru.

For a Sinatra application, I would use a Procfile that looks something like this:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340943/deploying-sinatra-app-with-config-ru-on-heroku-cedar-stack) similar question might be some help too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened but I just deleted my app on heroku and created a new one. Then it worked.  I think when I created the app originally, heroku thought the app was a node app because I was missing my Procfile.

Comment: Yikes!   I'm in the middle of migrating from Aspen to Cedar and have this problem.  I may have dione the first push without a Procfile.  It would seem like a nightmare to try to delete and recreate the app.   What does it mean "thought it was a node app", and is there any other way to persuade it that I'm not?