# How to Structure Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What's the best way to structure a Sinatra app that uses DataMapper? Make a db config file and require it from the main ruby file? How should migrations be handled?

Thanks

Comment: The padrino framework might be worth a look for your needs.  It is built on sinatra and migrating takes a matter of minutes.  http://padrinorb.com

Comment: This excellent answer may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5030173/366051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple you can configure your Datamapper settings in the configure block:

```
configure do
  #some Datamapper settings
end
```

No need to use extra files unless your project grows big.
That's the beauty of Sinatra, everything fits in one file.