# Before filter for models in a Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I am using Sinatra and have organized my application into models, views and routes (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030173/924643)).

I have come across several guides (such as [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#filters)) on using before filters with routes. Is there any way to use before filters for models?

I am using the Sinatra ActiveRecord extension if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord has such before filters out-of-the-box.
It supports `before_save`, `after_save`, `before_create`, `after_create`, and even `before_validation` and `after_validation`.

Look here for a detailed explanation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html