# How do you set up Rack::URLMap to work with RSpec in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, sinatra, rack

I'm relatively new to Sinatra, and I want to figure out a way to integrate RSpec with my Sinatra setup.

config.ru

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongoid'
require 'uri'
require './lib/twilio_wrapper'

Mongoid.load!("./config/mongoid.yml")

Dir["./controllers/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }

run Rack::URLMap.new(
  '/' => HomeController.new,
  '/users' => UsersController.new(TwilioWrapper.new)
)
```

With this setup, I can modularize my controllers and create single instances of helper classes (such as TwilioWrapper). However, if I want to set up RSpec, I need to point it to my application's class. However, in the situation above, because I'm using Rack::URLMap, I don't have a specific application class to point RSpec to.

How can I keep my code modular in the fashion outlined above while including RSpec for tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rack does not care about controllers, it cares about apps.  So `HomeController` and `UsersController` are 2 Sinatra applications "racked up" in Rack.  These are not controllers, they are separate Rack apps. I do not think you want 2 applications but rather to put these 2 controllers in 2 files so you can spec them out separately and keep the code readable.

The naming convention for Sinatra is to name it something like `MyApp` to reflect this.  Sinatra is a flat framework, but you can name your "controller" files what you want.

So in folder `routes` you can have 'users.rb' and 'home.rb' but both files have at the top

```
MyApp < Sinatra::Application
```

Then you can test using `Rack::Test` with Rspec.

If you do indeed want to test 2 apps and want the prefix using `Rack::Test` w Rspec you simply need to define `app` in your spec_helper or spec file as:

```
 def app
  run Rack::URLMap.new(
   '/' => HomeController.new,
   '/users' => UsersController.new(TwilioWrapper.new)
  )
 end
```

All `Rack::Test` does is rackup your Sinatra app into a test container.

Also please see Phrogz's excellent answer on [how to lay out a Sinatra application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015471/using-sinatra-for-larger-projects-via-multiple-files)

Comment: Great explanation. I think what I really needed in the end was the link to an example Sinatra app. I'm going to do a little bit of refactoring, and I should be good to go.