# Calling a helper method from a route in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've set up a simple Sinatra app based on [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030173/142486). My code is working and looks like this:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application

  set :public_folder, Proc.new { File.join(root, "app/public") }
  set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "app/views") }

  register Sinatra::Namespace
  register Sinatra::Flash
  enable :sessions

end

require_relative 'app/helpers/init'
require_relative 'app/models/init'
require_relative 'app/routes/init'
```

Then I have a dirty image uploader in a helper, which is being required in `app/helpers/init.rb`

```
# app/helpers/image.rb
require 'imgur'

module ImageUploader

  def save(image)
    @filename = image[:filename]
    file = image[:tempfile]
    File.open("#{ENV['PHOTO_TMP_DIR']}/#{@filename}", 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(file.read)
      upload(@filename)
    end
  end

  def upload(filename)
    client = Imgur.new(ENV['IMGUR_CLIENT_ID'])
    image = Imgur::LocalImage.new("#{ENV['PHOTO_TMP_DIR']}/#{@filename}")
    uploaded = client.upload(image)
    File.delete("#{ENV['PHOTO_TMP_DIR']}/#{@filename}")
    uploaded.link
  end

end
```

And I'm successfully calling the `save` method in my `app/routes/admin.rb` file, like so:

```
# app/routes/admin.rb
class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  ...
  imgur_url = save(params[:image])
  ...
end
```

The problem is that `save` method name is so generic. I've tried calling with `ImageUploader::save` and `ImageUploader.save`, but they both throw errors. Is there another way I can call this helper method and have it namespaced to the helper module?

I should note that I'm loading the helper method like this:

```
# app/helpers/init.rb
require_relative 'image'
MyApp.helpers ImageUploader
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! To namespace the module methods, put `self` in front of the method name. Now doing:

```
# app/helpers/image.rb
require 'imgur'

module ImageUploader

  def self.save(image)
    @filename = image[:filename]
    file = image[:tempfile]
    File.open("#{ENV['PHOTO_TMP_DIR']}/#{@filename}", 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(file.read)
      upload(@filename)
    end
  end

  def self.upload(filename)
    client = Imgur.new(ENV['IMGUR_CLIENT_ID'])
    image = Imgur::LocalImage.new("#{ENV['PHOTO_TMP_DIR']}/#{@filename}")
    uploaded = client.upload(image)
    File.delete("#{ENV['PHOTO_TMP_DIR']}/#{@filename}")
    uploaded.link
  end

end
```

Allows me to call `ImageUploader.save` without any errors.